Upgraded SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio to 2022. Got "Failed to Render Page" error
I upgraded SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio to the latest 2022 version. Using HTML Report viewer from .NET. The database is SQL Server.
Began getting a "Failed to Render Page" error on certain reports using images served from sql blob fields.  No other information.
Sorry to answer my own question but there are a lot of red herring answers out there from 10 years ago that no longer apply and send one in an entirely different direction, So I want to save time for people. I wasted quite a bit of time.
The correct answer in this case is to simply to delete and re-add the 'picture' field from the offending crystal report after upgrading.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hey, you're welcome to answer your own question, but make sure to keep the question in the question and post answer as answers, not in the question. Check the [tour]. That way others can post and vote for alternative answers.
